# Google Apps script - comparing the same values from array returns false

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to compare arrays from different pages from the sheet, but when comparing 2 exact same values it always returns false

```
function test123() {
  var ScanningThisArray = [["123"],["321"],["515"]];
  var ActiveEmployeeArray =  [["123"],["321"],["515"]];                

  for (var i = 0; i < ScanningThisArray.length; i++) {

    for (var k = 0; k < ActiveEmployeeArray.length; k++) {
      Logger.log(ScanningThisArray[i]+" == "+ActiveEmployeeArray[k]+" == "+(ScanningThisArray[i]==ActiveEmployeeArray[k]))

    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
[19-06-18 23:48:18:187 EEST] 123 == 123 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:187 EEST] 123 == 321 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:188 EEST] 123 == 515 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:188 EEST] 321 == 123 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:189 EEST] 321 == 321 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:189 EEST] 321 == 515 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:190 EEST] 515 == 123 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:190 EEST] 515 == 321 == false
[19-06-18 23:48:18:191 EEST] 515 == 515 == false
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was comparing array to array since google returns array for each cell and then puts it into another array, changed from

```
ScanningThisArray[i]==ActiveEmployeeArray[k]
```

to

```
ScanningThisArray[i][0]==ActiveEmployeeArray[k][0]
```

works fine now